# PHP Script in CPanel not running

Tags: php, html, apache, web, cpanel

I was transfering my website from Hostgator to a new server.
When I open the PHP page in my website, it will download the page rather than execute and showing the page, but if I open the HTML page, image, etc. It will open it like it should be.

What should I do so my Website can run the PHP script and showing the page rather than downloading it?

Comment: something is up with the apache config, its not recognizing the file as something to run

Answer (score -1):

Add some handlers to your .htaccess file so that it will recognize the php files and execute them as they should be